# HTAccess Rewrite rule affecting other pages?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've just created a rule for my .htaccess file to send any traffic going to...

`mysite.com/area-scheme.php?scheme_id=XXX`to appear as `mysite.com/london`

The below works fine for those pages, but if I visit mysite.com, its not loading data correctly and I have to actually visit mysite.com/index.php, have I done something wrong?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /area-scheme.php?scheme_id=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 2):

can you try this?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /area-scheme.php?scheme_id=$1 [L]
```

This may avoid rewriting mysite.com that has an empty relative URL.